# How are individual turnovers determined on errant passes?

Tags: basketball, officiating

When determining turnovers for a given player, how exactly are they determined? Wikipedia defines turnovers as

> In basketball, a turnover occurs when a player from one team gives possession to a member of the opposing team by losing the ball. This can result from the ball being stolen, the player making mistakes such as stepping out or throwing the ball out of bounds, or committing a violation (such as traveling) or committing an offensive foul.

However, I'm not clear on what happens on errant passes. When a player in possession of the ball makes a pass that is immediately intercepted by a defender, then obviously the player who passed the ball is charged with a turnover. My question is what happens if the ball is tipped by the player that the ball was intended for before the defender gains possession of the ball? Who is charged with a turnover in that situation, the player who made the pass or the player who tipped the ball before the defender gained possession? Is it determined by who touched the ball last or the player who last had full possession of the ball?

Comment: I have the same question about steals and rebounds, but I'm not sure yet whether or not they deserve another question. I will let the answer determine that

Comment: My gut tells me it's the last player to have confirmed touching the ball gets the turnover. But I wouldn't bet the farm on it.

Comment: It is always the passers turnover if the receiver is unable to receive the ball.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all comes down to who had the last **full possession** of the ball.

If player A on team 1 passed the ball, and player B on team 1 tipped it, and player A on team 2 caught it, the turnover would be player A1's fault.

*Note: As it was not specified, these are Middle/High School rules. I can not vouch that this is also an NBA or College rule*

**UPDATE: I FOUND [THIS](http://www.livestrong.com/article/419606-basketball-rules-what-are-turnovers/) BLOG IN WHICH IT STATES THAT, IN THE NBA, THE LAST PERSON TO TOUCH THE BALL IS GIVEN THE TURNOVER.**

Comment: I'd imagine professional stats would be done in the same way but let's confirm

Comment: @DmitrySelitskiy: See update.